# How to change the application/octet-stream type api response to document

Tags: c#, json-api-response-converter

** We want to get the pdf type document from api but api return octet-stream type response how to convert it as a document and save in our local system We attached the postman response screenshot ** ApiResponce-

%PDF-1.3 %���� 1 0 obj << /Type /Catalog /Outlines 2 0 R /Pages 3 0 R >> endobj 2 0 obj << /Type /Outlines /Count 0 >> endobj 3 0 obj << /Type /Pages /Count 2 /Kids [ 4 0 R 6 0 R ] >> endobj 4 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Resources << /Font << /F1 9 0 R >> /ProcSet 8 0 R >> /MediaBox [0 0 612.0000 792.0000] /Contents 5 0 R >> endobj 5 0 obj << /Length 1074 >> stream 2 J BT 0 0 0 rg /F1 0027 Tf 57.3750 722.2800 Td ( A Simple PDF File ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 688.6080 Td ( This is a small demonstration .pdf file - ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 664.7040 Td ( just for use in the Virtual Mechanics tutorials. More text. And more ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 652.7520 Td ( text. And more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 628.8480 Td ( And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 616.8960 Td ( text. And more text. Boring, zzzzz. And more text. And more text. And ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 604.9440 Td ( more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 592.9920 Td ( And more text. And more text. ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 569.0880 Td ( And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 557.1360 Td ( text. And more text. And more text. Even more. Continued on page 2 ...) Tj ET endstream endobj 6 0 obj << /Type /Page /Parent 3 0 R /Resources << /Font << /F1 9 0 R >> /ProcSet 8 0 R >> /MediaBox [0 0 612.0000 792.0000] /Contents 7 0 R >> endobj 7 0 obj << /Length 676 >> stream 2 J BT 0 0 0 rg /F1 0027 Tf 57.3750 722.2800 Td ( Simple PDF File 2 ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 688.6080 Td ( ...continued from page 1. Yet more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 676.6560 Td ( And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 664.7040 Td ( text. Oh, how boring typing this stuff. But not as boring as watching ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 652.7520 Td ( paint dry. And more text. And more text. And more text. And more text. ) Tj ET BT /F1 0010 Tf 69.2500 640.8000 Td ( Boring. More, a little more text. The end, and just as well. ) Tj ET endstream endobj 8 0 obj [/PDF /Text] endobj 9 0 obj << /Type /Font /Subtype /Type1 /Name /F1 /BaseFont /Helvetica /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding >> endobj 10 0 obj << /Creator (Rave ([http://www.nevrona.com/rave\](http://www.nevrona.com/rave%5C))) /Producer (Nevrona Designs) /CreationDate (D:20060301072826) >> endobj xref 0 11 0000000000 65535 f 0000000019 00000 n 0000000093 00000 n 0000000147 00000 n 0000000222 00000 n 0000000390 00000 n 0000001522 00000 n 0000001690 00000 n 0000002423 00000 n 0000002456 00000 n 0000002574 00000 n trailer << /Size 11 /Root 1 0 R /Info 10 0 R >> startxref 2714 %%EOF

How to change the this api responce to original documnet Using c#

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).